# Variable is set as string but undefined as object property

Tags: php, undefined, isset

What is the explanation for this apparent contradiction?

When using isset the variable $city = ''; returns 'true'.

However I have to use an if statement in the following code to avoid the undefined error:

```
class Holiday {

public $city = '';

public function __construct() {
        if (isset($city)) {
        $this->city = $city;
        }
        }

public function get_city() {
        return $this->city;
}

public function set_city($city) {
        return $this->city = $city;
}
}

$germany = new Holiday;

$germany->set_city('Berlin');

function travel($a) {
echo "Visit " . $a->get_city();
}
```

I have searched for an explanation between 'is set' and undefined but can't find one. I would really appreciate any insights.

Comment: isset checks if variable is defined or not.

Comment: @IanStewart where you get this error? Sure not in your example code, even without modify it.

Comment: @fusion 3k the error occurs when I use the set_city($city) function. If I pass the value directly the object (i.e. 'Berlin') it works anyway.

Comment: It is because in global scope `$city` is not defined. In my answer there is a link to variable scopes. Your `$city` is defined inside `Holiday` class: you can access it by `$this->city` inside class methods, or by `$germany->city` after instantiating `$germany` object. Outside class, `$city` has nothing to do with `Holiday::city`. You have to declare it (i.e. `$city = 'Hamburg'`). But it has nothing to do with `$city` inside class. In other words, `$city='Hamburg'; $germany->set_city($city);` is equal to `$var='Hamburg'; $germany->set_city($var);`

Comment: The problem is that $city creates the 'undefined error' in the class definition. This code

Comment: @fusion 3k The problem is that $city creates the 'undefined error' in the class definition itself. in the __construct($city) function it shows an error with this line  $this->city = $city; irrespective of how I instantiate the object.

Comment: It is not possible. Your code must be different from example above , or the error is generate elsewhere. Your example code **does not** generate any Notice. [See for yourself](https://eval.in/526620).

Comment: Thanks for your replay fusion 3k. That version works because the 'if (isset($city)) {'  is included, I was trying to get it to work without using 'isset'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a $city variable in the constructor, that's why you are  getting that error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just added $city in the constructor but still get the 'Undefined variable' error.

Comment: Do you pass it to the object when you are creating it ?

Comment: That works. However it is going to make the code complex as in the class I am using there are 10 variables, some 150 characters long. The 'global' or 'if' statement approach certainly makes the code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's a “variable scope” issue.

Inside `__construct`, local variable `$city` is not set.

You have to pass it through arguments:

```
 public function __construct( $city )
```

Or to declare it as global, depending by your goals:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     global $city;
```

But I think that you are in search of first solution.

---

- Read more about [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)